# index by time cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

In mysql if would like to index some rows by for example by time I would index the column time and every time I would enter new data it would get indexed automatically and it would look like that if would like to retrieve the data using that index

```
data| time
1| 22-6-2013
2| 21-5-2013
3| 20-4-2013
```

- How could I do the same in cassandra?

One way I could think of is by creating an object with a primary index (not using uuid) looking like that `20-4-2013` and then literally search through every date beginning at for example 22-6-2013 (the highest) until I find an object or row.

- Is there another way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a "CompositeKey" table, in the form of:

```
CREATE TABLE timetable(
unique_id varchar,
time timestamp,
other_data varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (unique_id, time)
);
```

Then you can use the following query:

> select * from timetable order by time desc;

or

> select * from timetable time > '2012-11-24' order by time desc;

you can also order "ascendent" just change "desc" to "asc"...

Comment: cql3, you can write it launching: "cqlsh --cql3" (you find this in the "bin" directory of the cassandra distribution), then you can "CREATE" the "timetable", and make the queries. Not sure how you use Cassandra... Furthermore, not sure if (CompositeKeys) are supported on Cassandra 0.7, you probably should use a more recent version too.